# Project Online COM/Odata call in MS Project VSTO Addin using current user context

Tags: authentication, odata, vsto, csom, project-online

I am developing a MS Project VSTO Addin through which I need to perform Project Online ODATA and CSOM calls. Is it possible that as the user is already authenticated using the Project Professional client we can carry out the CSOM/ODATA calls in that context only without authenticating the calls again.
I tried making ODATA and CSOM calls in Addin with out passing the credentials and getting 403 error.

We can perform the Odata call in VBA code of Project Professional and it works with out passing any authentication token/credential i.e it is working with logged in user context only.
So, is there something we can do in VSTO Addin too to carry out the CSOM/ODATA calls without setting projContext.Credentials value .

Answer (score 0):

VSTO doesn't provide anything for that unfortunately. You need to keep using the `Credentials` property value.